# Json Parsing and summing up the values inside json

Tags: javascript, json

I have a set of json values as shown below

```
{"labels":[ "time", "softirq", "user", "system", "nice", "iowait" ], "data":[ [ 1490088352, 0, 14.64646, 3.53535, 0, 1.0101 ], [ 1490088351, 0, 27.77778, 3.0303, 0, 0 ], [ 1490088350, 0.49751, 12.93532, 2.98508, 0, 4.47761 ] }
```

I want to parse this json .sum up the labels `{ "softirq", "user", "system", "nice", "iowait"}` values and store in separate value  named "sum". My final output should be like shown below :

```
{ "time" : 1490088352 , "sum": "the value which we added "}
{"time" : 1490088351 , "sum": "the value which we added "}
{"time" : 1490088350 , "sum": "the value which we added "}
```

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Comment: please add an example with numbers as result. what means *"sum up the labels "*? all in one or label by label?

Comment: .. The labels are { time , softirq , user , system , nice , iowait } . I need to add new column sum ( added values of softirq, user, system, nice,iowait)  with respect to time. Final output : example : { "time" : 1490088352 , "sum": 20.822}

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to reduce array to a single value

`Array.slice(1)` will return array excluding first value

```js
var data = {
  "labels": ["time", "softirq", "user", "system", "nice", "iowait"],
  "data": [
    [1490088352, 0, 14.64646, 3.53535, 0, 1.0101],
    [1490088351, 0, 27.77778, 3.0303, 0, 0],
    [1490088350, 0.49751, 12.93532, 2.98508, 0, 4.47761]
  ]
};
var op = [];
data.data.forEach(function(el) {
  var obj = {
    time: el[0]
  };
  obj.sum = el.slice(1).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
  op.push(obj);
});
console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this, first load the data,

```
var values= {
  "labels": ["time", "softirq", "user", "system", "nice", "iowait"],
  "data": [
    [1490088352, 0, 14.64646, 3.53535, 0, 1.0101],
    [1490088351, 0, 27.77778, 3.0303, 0, 0],
    [1490088350, 0.49751, 12.93532, 2.98508, 0, 4.47761]
  ]
};
```

then,

```
var answer = values.data.map(function(d){return {"time":d[0], "sum": d.splice(1,d.length).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)};});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var source = {
  "labels": ["time", "softirq", "user", "system", "nice", "iowait"],
  "data": [
    [1490088352, 0, 14.64646, 3.53535, 0, 1.0101],
    [1490088351, 0, 27.77778, 3.0303, 0, 0],
    [1490088350, 0.49751, 12.93532, 2.98508, 0, 4.47761]
  ]
};

    var  data =source.data;


var mydata = [];
var eachObject={};

for(var i in data){
  sum=0;
  eachObject={};
  for(var j=1,l=data[i].length;j<l;j++ ){
    sum+=data[i][j];
  }

  eachObject.time=data[i][0];
  eachObject.sum=sum;
  mydata.push(eachObject);

  console.log(mydata);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
﻿
﻿

var arr= {"labels":[ "time", "softirq", "user", "system", "nice", "iowait" ], "data":[ [ 1490088352, 0, 14.64646, 3.53535, 0, 1.0101 ], [ 1490088351, 0, 27.77778, 3.0303, 0, 0 ], [ 1490088350, 0.49751, 12.93532, 2.98508, 0, 4.47761 ]] };
var op = [];
for(var i =0; i < arr.data.length; i++){
    var obj = {};
    obj.time = arr.data[i][0];
    obj.sum = 0;
    for(var j = 1; j < arr.data[i].length; j++){
        obj.sum += arr.data[i][j];
    }
    op.push(obj);
}
console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array with the wanted labels for sum and a hash table for the time grouping.

```js
var data = { "labels": ["time", "softirq", "user", "system", "nice", "iowait"], "data": [[1490088352, 0, 14.64646, 3.53535, 0, 1.0101], [1490088351, 0, 27.77778, 3.0303, 0, 0], [1490088350, 0.49751, 12.93532, 2.98508, 0, 4.47761]] },
    labels = ["softirq", "user", "system", "nice", "iowait"],
    result = data.data.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            if (!hash[a[0]]) {
                hash[a[0]] = { time: a[0], sum: 0 };
                r.push(hash[a[0]]);
            }
            hash[a[0]].sum += labels.reduce(function (r, l) { return r + (a[data.labels.indexOf(l)] || 0); }, 0);
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)),[]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var data = {
      "labels": ["time", "softirq", "user", "system", "nice", "iowait"],
      "data": [
        [1490088352, 0, 14.64646, 3.53535, 0, 1.0101],
        [1490088351, 0, 27.77778, 3.0303, 0, 0],
        [1490088350, 0.49751, 12.93532, 2.98508, 0, 4.47761]
      ]
    };
    var op = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++){
  var json = {"time" : data.data[i][0], "sum" : 0}
  for(var j = 1; j < data.data[i].length; j++){
        json.sum += data.data[i][j];
  }
   op.push(json)
}
console.log(op)
```